Convert dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel> to torch at::Tensor
I trained torch model and converted pth to script module using this tutorial. Then I made custom c++ project like here.
Modified this example to input tensor like this:
const std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs(1, torch::ones({1, 3, inputSize, inputSize}));
auto output = module.forward(inputs).toTensor();
std::cout << "raw output: " << output << '\n'
          << "soft max: " << torch::softmax(output, 1)
          << '\n';

NB1 inputSize about 128 or 256 pixels (have few exported modules). This inputs works
Now I have dlib image like dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel>. I tried load blob data:
at::Tensor convert(const dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel> & img)
{
    auto options = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kUInt8);
    std::vector<int64_t> dims = {1, 3, img.nr(), img.nc()};
    auto t = torch::from_blob((void*)img.begin(), dims/*, options*/).clone();

    return t;
}

But if I cout resulting tensor there are several number with 1e+38 or 1e+40; and result after forward through model I have nan in module.forward(tensorFromConverFunction).toTensor().
NB2 maybe some slice may help but I can't figure out the solution.

at::Tensor convert(const dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel> & img)
{
    const auto height = img.nr();
    const auto width = img.nc();
    auto tensor = at::zeros({1, 3, height, width});

    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            tensor[0][0][y][x] = img[y][x].blue;
            tensor[0][1][y][x] = img[y][x].green;
            tensor[0][2][y][x] = img[y][x].red;
        }
    }

    return tensor;
}

